# Vue 3 vue-router не работает в production mode

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, webpack, vue-router

Делаю CRM. У всех страниц в настройках роутера есть мета-свойство layout, определяющее, в какой обёртке будет представлен контент этой страницы

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    meta: {layout: 'auth'},
    component: () => import('@/views/LoginPage.vue')
  },
  {
    path: "/planning",
    name: "Planning",
    meta: {layout: 'main', auth: true},
    component: () => import('@/views/PlanningPage.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/categories',
    name: "Categories",
    meta: {layout: 'main', auth: true},
    component: () => import('@/views/CategoriesPage.vue')
  },
```

В корневом компоненте App вложено computed свойство , которое запрашивает это мета-свойство у $route, то есть у текущей страницы. За счёт этого computed свойства работает динамический компонент, который и оборачивает router-view

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </component>
</template>
<script>
import MainLayout from './layouts/MainLayout.vue';
import AuthLayout from './layouts/AuthLayout.vue';
export default {
  data(){
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    layout(){
      return this.$route.meta.layout + '-layout'
    }
  },
  components: {
    MainLayout, AuthLayout
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("checkForAuth")
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

Итак, в developer mode всё работает замечательно - vue-router цепляет нужные страницы, меняет динамический компонент на нужный (main-layout или auth-layout), и выводит всё на экран:

[image: Developer mode]

В production mode, запускаемом через `file://` меня, вместо нужного layout, встречает undefined-layout, ничего не работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самостоятельно решения проблемы не нашёл, лучшее, к чему пришёл - по всей видимости почему-то не работает `this.$route.meta`.
Если хардкодить layout в App.vue, впрочем, общая проблема не решается. В production mode выводится лишь navbar, заложенный в layout'e, а сами страницы также не подгружаются.
Заранее спасибо за помощь, если вам потребуются уточнения - готов действовать оперативно!

*vue.config.js:*

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: '@import "~@/assets/variables.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

*настройки роутера*

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currUser = auth.currentUser,
        requireAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)
  if(requireAuth && !currUser)
    next('/login')
  else next()
})

export default router;
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Картинки с исходным кодом исправлены на текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена. Для открытия приложения через `file://` протокол необходимо использовать `createWebHashHistory` в настройках роутера, всё, что было нужно для решения проблемы - залить приложение на хостинг

Comment: "На локале не работает, а на проде - работает". Супер